# Контракты в Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Где в Laravel 5.4 хранятся контракты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратимся к документации ? Вот часть про [контракты](http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/contracts). Исходя из написанного можно предположить что контракты Laravel лежат в папке `Illuminate\Contracts`.

Но это же просто место расположения файлов, вы можете определить интерфейс в любом удобном вам месте, в вашем модуле/пакете и использовать его при разработке.

Мне кажется изменять (добавять\удалаять код\файлы) исходники фреймворка не удачная идея

Comment: Спасибо. Я понял. Но вот никак не пойму, как здесь благодарить за ответ, может подскажите?

Comment: Отметьте ответ как правильный :)

Comment: Но как? Нигде такого нет.

Comment: я даже не знаю как объяснить :) [справка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Под голосами ответа есть галочка, нажмите на неё, чтобы она стала зеленой.